# How to clear view pager fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a `fragment A`, in it I have a view pager with two `fragment 1.1` and `fragment 1.2`
these fragments are children fragments of `fragment A` .

Now when the user gets to Fragment B and then back to A I need to update the 
child fragments 1.1 and 1.2 by the options inside fragment B.
The problem is I can`t update the fragments as they are already inside childfragment manager, also when I return back to fragment A `getItem(int position)` of the view pager not called.
I managed to remove all the child fragments before I am setting the view pager adapter but I am not sure this it the right way to accomplish this functionality.

I have 1.1 and 1.2 references inside Fragment A

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem. For me it worked to override FragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {

}
```

This work for me.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way (not the best way) to do this is to override `getItemPosition()` in your `PagerAdapter`:

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

When the adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method is called, the `ViewPager` will call `getItemPosition()` on the views it already knows about.  By returning POSITION_NONE, you are telling the `ViewPager` to remove the view.  Once the `ViewPager` removes the view, it will call `getItem()` to get an updated view.

So when the user returns back to Fragment A you would call:

```
viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This will start the process of updating all your views.

Comment: Hi Kris, thanks for the reply but when I came back from fragment B to A I am building the adapter once again.

Comment: I created a function 
public void setData(List<BaseFragment> data)
 {
  _fragData = data;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
I called it after I set the adapter to the viewpager but still no effect

Comment: That is the better way to do it.  Note that calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` for `PagerAdapter` is meant to mean that the pages have changed places; it's different from an `AdapterVIew` adapter in that it doesn't handle a change in the item itself.  In your `setData()`, you might try calling `getView().invalidate()` on the fragment to refresh the view with your data.  Be sure to check that `getView()` is not null, because it will be when the fragment isn't rendered.

Comment: The problem is after I called notifyDataSetChanged() in setData the getItem(int position) never called, I added getItemPosition but without luck

Comment: What happens if you call `getView().invalidate()` at the end of `setData()`?

Comment: I tried to invalidate the hole parent fragment but without success, I can still see the previous selection of fragment 1.1 before I entered to Fragment B. The data is correct but it seems the fragments not updated correctly.

Comment: If you did the override for `getItemPosition()` to return `POSITION_NONE`, then `getItem()` should definitely be called.  Try setting debug breakpoints or adding logging statements in your adapter.  After you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter, you should see `getCount()` called a few times, then `getItemPosition()` should be called for each fragment, and if you're returning `POSITION_NONE`, then `getItem()` should be called.

Comment: Maybe you could post some code, so the community can look at it and locate any problems.

Comment: Hi Kris,
I created a sample project but I works without overriding getItemPosition in the adapter and without setData. Can I sent it to you because I can`t attach files here.

Comment: Or even better, throw it up onto GitHub and send me the link.  If you don't have a GitHub account, sure, you can just send it to me.

Comment: Oh wow.  Okay, I didn't expect that fragment B was going to *replace* fragment A, then fragment A was going to *replace* fragment B when B was done.  First off, I wouldn't have any transaction code in the fragments themselves.  I would have a method in the activity that receives the data from B then runs the transaction to redisplay A.  Also, rather than replace, I would hide A, add B and save to back stack, then when B posts new data to the activity, the activity would just pop the stack, then update A with the data.  A would then update the page fragments.  To be continued...

Comment: It`s not replacing A it`s popping out fragment from backstack.

Comment: It`s not replacing A it`s popping out fragment from backstack.
I need this functionality I have few views that have streams from remote computer. So I can`t add several fragments of A fragment(has streams views). " the activity would just pop the stack, then update A with the data. A would then update the page fragments." That what I am doing I am checking if I have fragment by calling findFragmentByTag, if I have instance of it i am popping fragments until I am not getting to fragment A, before I am getting to fragment A I am setting the arguments of A .
I can`t set arguments twice.

Answer (score 3):

You should use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just call :

```
viewPager.removeAllViews()
viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help,can you add an explanation ? How this code will resolve the problem.